# Jest throwing TypeError : this.inputEl.focus is not a function #1964

Tags: javascript, jestjs, stenciljs

**Stencil version:**

```
 @stencil/core@1.7.0
```

**Jest version:**

```
   "jest": "24.8.0"
```

**Current behavior:**

I am trying to focus  a input element on button click.
Which works fine, however upon trying to test the functionality using `npm test` , `jest` throws a `TypeError` saying **focus is not a function.**

This bug is being repeated for all the manual event invoke like `click`, `blur`, `focus` .
 Hence the test cases doesn't pass.

**Expected behavior:**

It should not throw error.

**Steps to reproduce:**

I am providing a related demo code for inspection purpose.
**Related code:**

**`demo-btn.tsx`**

```
import { Component, h, Element } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'demo-btn',
  styleUrl: 'demo-btn.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class DemoBtnComponent {
  @Element() el!: HTMLElement;
  private inputEl?: HTMLElement;

  onClick = () => {
    if (this.inputEl) {
      this.inputEl.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="input-container">
        <input ref={el => this.inputEl = el} type="text" />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>
          Click Me
      </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**`demo-btn.spec.tsx`**

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { DemoBtnComponent } from './demo-btn';

describe('my-component', () => {
  it('should focus input el on btn click', async ()=> {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [DemoBtnComponent],
      html: '<demo-btn></demo-btn>',
    });

    const btn = page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('button')
    btn.click(); // Throws error after this line
    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(true).toBeTruthy(); // For sake of completion
  });
});
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Resolved this issue by mocking `focus` of input element.
Below is the code I tried out:

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { DemoBtnComponent } from './demo-btn';

describe('my-component', () => {
  it('should focus input el on btn click', async ()=> {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [DemoBtnComponent],
      html: '<demo-btn></demo-btn>',
    });

    /** Mock Input Elements focus function */
    const inputEl = page.root.querySelector('input');
    inputEl.focus = jest.fn();


    const btn = page.root.querySelector('button')
    btn.click();
    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Closing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue, however the above solution doesn't work if the focus() function is within a Lifecycle event. So, to fix this, I used optional chaining in the code itself:

```
this.inputEl?.focus?.();
```

More details in this article: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1964